# Combinations and permutations (Evergreen)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many strings with seven or more characters can be formed from the letters in EVERGREEN if the two R's are consecutive?

I know how to do this if the two R's don't have to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

$7$ or more characters from $EVERGEEN$

plus $\Sigma[k$ characters from $EVEGEEN)\times(k+1)], k = 5\;\; to\;\; 7$